# Place collectionView group name on Position.Start

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a `CollectionView` with some groups. I would like to try to scroll it and place the group name in the Start position.

```
public class Group : ObservableCollection<Diary>
{
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Group(string name, ObservableCollection<Diary> icon) : base(icon)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
 }

Group group = new Group(Mese + " " + hd.Dt.Year.ToString(), new ObservableCollection<Diary>());
ListGroup.Add(group);

var Find = ListGroup.First(x => x.Name == Name + " " + time.Year.ToString());
   
CollectionDiary.ScrollTo(Find, position: ScrollToPosition.Start);
```

With this code, the `CollectionView` makes a small scroll but never positions itself in the desired point. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What's the means of `a small scroll ` ? You could post the full code(xaml and code behind) ,which will be helpful to find out the cause .

Comment: I have updated the code. The collectionview moves slightly, at most it moves by one element, when in reality it should move by 5 elements, so I can't see the correct CollectionView group

Comment: Where you declare CollectionView, did you do `IsGroup` property set to `true`? (Though since you did ScrollToPosition.Start, I would think it would work anyway.) OR since `Find` is a group, does it belong in the *second* parameter (`group`) to ScrollTo?